# Search for word recursively in open file in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I usually use following way to search particularly words in open files in vim

```
:/word-name
```

It works but if there are several occurances of a word then I'll have to type of every single time to go to the next matching word. Is there a way to search the open file for words in vim and I keep pressing enter which will take me to next matching word rather keep typing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just type 'n' and the next hit is highlighted. See ["Find next" in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607630/find-next-in-vim).

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for the word by pressing '/' and typing the desired word
2. Then to get the next occurrence of the word, press 'n'

Extra Tips:

To get to the previous occurence of the word, press 'N'

Also, you can go to the next occurence of the word that your cursor is on by using '*'